# MySQL Laravel how to multiply by array of values

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have `products` table which has `id, price, name` , and I am receiving an array of products id and quantity from front-end, what I want is to calculate the sum of price*quantity.

I know that I can use PHP foreach, but I am looking for database way

```
//Laravel php way

$sum = 0;
foreach($request->items as $item)
{
     product = Product::find($item['product_id']);
     $sum += $product->price*$item['quantity']
}
```

what I want is to pass the array to mysql and make mysql handle the calculation.

Comment: You want to use Eloquent or query builder?

Comment: @AyèchHamza I want to use Query builder

Comment: where you get ` $product->price`  ? is this code part wrapped with a loop?

Comment: @AyèchHamza Updated my question and provided product

Answer (score 0):

Do you keep the quantity of the item in the database? If you are happy, you can reach the result you want after a small query, but you need to tell us the details of the structure you have prepared.